# How to create script that counts divs not hidden and updates as user applies filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble creating script to count/display the number of divs that the user has selected to display compared to the total amount of divs available.

Here is a JSFiddle showing the entire problem. http://jsfiddle.net/rcmb06om/

Here is the script i'm using to count both the total number of divs with a class and then trying to count the total number of divs with a class:visible.

```
$( document.body ).append( $( "<div>" ) );
var n = $(".rResult").length;
$( "#totalresults" ).text( n);

$( document.body ).append( $( "<div>" ) );
var x = $(".rResult").filter(":visible").length;
 $( "#activeresults" ).text( x);
```

Comment: if you deselect the colors, the text should update to (0 of 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have update code and demo. on change of drop down and on click on check box i am now counting the visible results. hope this will help you

```
window.filter = function() {
var totalColors = 0;
$('#month-select').change(function() {
  window.filter();
  updateCounter();
});
window.Color = {
  filterByColor: function() {
    window.filter();
    updateCounter();
  },
  filterByColorSelectAll: function() {
    if ($("#selectall").is(":checked"))
      $(".checkColor").prop("checked", "checked");
    else
      $(".checkColor").removeProp("checked");
    window.filter();
    updateCounter();
  },
}
window.filter = function() {

  var month = $('#month-select').val();
  if (month == null || month == "")
    $('.rResult').show(); //show all
  else {
    $('.rResult').hide(); // hide all 
    $('.rResult.' + month).show(); //filter by month
  }

  var strColorFilter = [];
  var checkedItems = $(".checkColor:not(:checked)").map(function(i, o) {
    return "." + o.id;
  }).get();
  //filter by color
  if (checkedItems.length == 0) return;
  strColorFilter.push(".rResult:visible"); //take on visible after month filter
  strColorFilter.push(checkedItems);
  $(strColorFilter.join("")).hide();

}


    $( document.body ).append( $( "<div>" ) );
    var n = $(".rResult").length;
    $( "#totalresults" ).text( n);

    $( document.body ).append( $( "<div>" ) );
    var x = $(".rResult").filter(":visible").length;
     $( "#activeresults" ).text( x);

    function updateCounter(){
        var totalColors = 0;
      totalColors = $(".rResult:visible").length;
      if(totalColors == -1){totalColors = 0;}
      $("#activeresults").html(totalColors);
    }
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/rcmb06om/7/

Comment: thanks for your effort Farhan but i'm not able to get that script to work at all.

Comment: can you check in you console if there is any JS error. as this is working on demo

Comment: i have updated the code, now on change of drop down counter is being update as well as on click of check box. please have a look on demo

Comment: thanks so much Farhan, life saver, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You should update the text you want when checkboxes change. i.e. in the `Color.filterByColor` & `Color.filterByColorSelectAll` events.

Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/rcmb06om/5/